# Use Java to fill out forms, possibly controlling a browser?

Tags: java, cookies, post

Is it possibly, at this point in time, to fill out a post form through Java? The problem with me not just using other tools is that the page has to be logged in with an account, then I can fill out the form. It's a simple form, with only 3 inputs - Name, EMail, Date of birth (text). But I need the cookies set to be able to fill them out.

Here's my current method:

```
public static void doSubmit(String url, HashMap<String, String> data) throws Exception {
    URL siteUrl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "user=john; pass=password");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    System.out.println("Debug 1: URL = "+url);

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    Set keys = data.keySet();
    Iterator keyIter = keys.iterator();
    String content = "";
    for(int i=0; keyIter.hasNext(); i++) {
        Object key = keyIter.next();
        if(i!=0) {
            content += "&";
        }
        content += key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key), "UTF-8");
    }
//  System.out.println(content);
    out.writeBytes(content);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

I found this method from another site, and here's the hashmap

```
        data.put("name", "name");
        data.put("email", "email@email.com");
        data.put("dob", "1/1/1900");
        doSubmit("link.com/index.php", data);
```

Is there a simpler method? Possibly controlling a browser, such as Chrome to fill it out automatically?

Comment: Storing user/pass in a cookie is a huge security hole. Fix it as soon as possible. Or if it isn't your site, report it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) and [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). These can be fronted by [JWebUnit](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/) if you need to swap implementations.

For something as trivial as this, [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) might be enough, but there'd be more manual work.

Answer (score 5):

Use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net). It's a programmatic Java web browser. You just tell it to go to a URL, fill some text field with some text, click on the submit button, and it returns the next page, just as you would do with a GUI.